# CSS input tag uneven length in Chrome and IE (relative to Firefox)

Tags: css, google-chrome, input

Chrome renders longer input fields than Firefox and IE.

I have tried a plethora of things, most of which I already forgot; but nevertheless, none worked.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5optv4q/3/)

```css
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .f1 {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 440px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 90px;
    top: 3px;
  }
  #id1,
  #id2 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 100px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  #id2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .btn {
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    position: relative;
    top: -90px;
    left: 289px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 0;
    background: #00ade2;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="firstlog">
  <form class="f1">
    <h1 id="user">ALREADY AN USER? LOGIN</h2>
      <p>
        <input id="id1">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input id="id2">
      </p> 
          <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN"> 
    </form>
    </section>
```

And if it helps, this is how it looks within the context of the remaining code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVS61.jpg

Comment: Its working fine for me, tested in all browers. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Didn't even think about cache. Still, tried doing that just now; still did not work. Strange. I found a different solution already, however: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You Should give box-sizing that should unify the width of the input fields

```
input,textarea,select  {
-ms-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

You should also add in padding and border so that user agents don't take precedence over them as well as they tend to change browser to browser.

**Noticed that you where using padding to make the width of your inputs if you really shouldn't do this as when you add in text it would create hell use width instead.**

P.s. you'll find that Firefox is actually the one in the wrong here it add's extra pixels to the input fields.

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5optv4q/5/)

```css
input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.f1 {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 440px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  top: 3px;
}
#id1,
#id2 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 270px;
  border: 0;
  ;
}
#id2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  left: 289px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
  background: #00ade2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstlog">

  <form class="f1">
    <h1 id="user">ALREADY AN USER? LOGIN</h2>
  <p>
    <input id="id1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="id2">
  </p> 
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN"> 
</form>


</section>
```

Comment: you are missing width and are compensating using padding try this fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

Added

```
    input[type="text"], fieldset.elist {
      width: 280 px;
}
```

to the CSS and it worked for all browsers. Yay!

Edit: Interestingly enough, the update works locally on all browsers but not on JsFiddle.